# Tomcat not running in Eclipse, but runs from cmd with the .bat file

Tags: eclipse, tomcat8.5

Tomcat runs successfully from the startup.bat file in CMD, but it isn't working in Eclipse. (At one point it was working just fine)

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and provide more details.

Comment: What is the error when starting from eclipse?

Comment: This is the start of the error:   SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component

Comment: The problem was within my web.xml file, and now that I fixed the ordering with the server-mapping etc. that long error message is not showing anymore.  All I get now is a 404 error message and an INFO message when Tomcat is starting up that says, "At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time."

Comment: @LMC Would you be able to help me figure this out?